# How to generate GraphQL Documentation Explorer

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-docs) to generate the Graphql docs.

This is the query I have used

```
function fetcher(query) {
  const queryLog = gql`myquery`;
  return fetch(window.location.origin + '/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query: queryLog,
    }),
  }).then(function(r) {
    return r.json();
  });
}
```

But it throws me the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'GraphQLDocs' of undefined
```

Can someone please help how can I use this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the package at the top of the script

```js
import { GraphQLDocs } from 'graphql-docs';
```

Change the render to

```js
<GraphQLDocs fetcher={fetcher} />
```

The documentation is not updated. There is an example included in the source code
https://github.com/mhallin/graphql-docs/tree/master/example

Not recommended to use this package as it did not update since 2 years ago.